# In Sieve of Eratosthenes implementation with Haskell, why are the multiples of 3,5,7.. not removed from the list?

Tags: haskell, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I'm currently self-studying the book *The Haskell Road to Logic, Maths and Programming* by Doets and Eijck, and I'm in the chapter 3.

In this chapter, the authors provides a Haskell code for the implementation of *Sieve of Eratosthenes* algorithm, and I did not like their implementation, so I tried to give my own implementation; however, **my version of the code does only removes the multiples of 2, and I couldn't figure out the reason for that**.Here is the code:

```
sieve :: [Int] -> [Int]
sieve (0:xs) = sieve xs
sieve (x:xs) = x : sieve (mark x 2 xs)
 where
 mark :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
 mark n k (y:ys)
  | y == n*k = 0 : (mark n (k+1) ys)
  | otherwise = y : (mark n (k) ys)
```

and the output is

```
*Ch3> sieve [2..]
[2,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35,37,39,41,43,45,47,49,51,...
```

**So, why does the code do not do the same removal operation of the multiples of, the other numbers, such as 3,5,7.. ?**

Comment: Plug for [The Genuine Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf) by Melissa E. O'Neill

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Short answer: The counter `k` in `mark` doesn't increment for `n` > 2.

`mark x 2 [2..]` correctly strips the evens from the list, and so the next step is calling `sieve [3,5..]`, which amounts to `3:sieve (mark 3 2 [5,7..])`, so let's see what happens here.

`mark 3 2 [5,7..]` (presumably) attempts to remove all the multiples of `3` from the list, but it does this step-by-step, first attempting to remove 6 from the list. However, as the list only contains odd numbers, 6 is never removed from the list, and the first case always fails. The code continues to check against 6, never moving up to remove 9.

Similarly, 25 is never removed, since the code only tries to remove `2*5` from the list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have now changed the implementation of the code, and it works now.